# Matlab imagesc plotting nan values

Tags: matlab, plot

When using imagesc to visualize data that contains NaN values, Matlab treats them as the minimum value(in gray it paints them black, jet - blue, etc). the jet colormap doesn't contain neither black nor white. is it possible to display the nan values as black/white?
for example:

```
data = [0 0 0 ; .5 .5 .5 ;1 1 1;nan nan nan];
```

should yield blue-green-red-black strips.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wrote a custom function to display `NaN` values as see-through, i.e. with an alpha value of 0.

```
function h = imagesc2 ( img_data )
% a wrapper for imagesc, with some formatting going on for nans

% plotting data. Removing and scaling axes (this is for image plotting)
h = imagesc(img_data);
axis image off

% setting alpha values
if ndims( img_data ) == 2
  set(h, 'AlphaData', ~isnan(img_data))
elseif ndims( img_data ) == 3
  set(h, 'AlphaData', ~isnan(img_data(:, :, 1)))
end

if nargout < 1
  clear h
end
```

The `NaN`s will thus be displayed the same colour as the figure background colour. If you remove the line `axis image off`, then the `NaN`s will be shown the same colour as the axis background colour. The function assumes the input images are of size `n x m` (single channel) or `n x m x 3` (three channels), so may need some modification depending on your use.

With your data:

```
data = [0 0 0 ; .5 .5 .5 ;1 1 1;nan nan nan];
imagesc2(data);
axis on
set(gca, 'Color', [0, 0, 0])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
function imagescnan(IM)
% function imagescnan(IM)
% -- to display NaNs in imagesc as white/black

% white
nanjet = [ 1,1,1; jet  ];
nanjetLen = length(nanjet); 
pctDataSlotStart = 2/nanjetLen;
pctDataSlotEnd   = 1;
pctCmRange = pctDataSlotEnd - pctDataSlotStart;

dmin = nanmin(IM(:));
dmax = nanmax(IM(:));
dRange = dmax - dmin;   % data range, excluding NaN

cLimRange = dRange / pctCmRange;
cmin = dmin - (pctDataSlotStart * cLimRange);
cmax = dmax;
imagesc(IM);
set(gcf,'colormap',nanjet);
caxis([cmin cmax]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Bill Cheatham mentioned, you can use,

```
set(h, 'AlphaData', ~isnan(img_data(:, :, 1)))
```

For something more generalisable, I would change this to

```
  set(h, 'AlphaData', ~isnan(h.CData))
```

This uses the image handle so that you don't have to worry about indexing your input image.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible ways of achieving this:

a) Modify the jet colormap so that its minimum value is black or white, e.g.:

```
cmap = jet;
cmap = [ 0 0 0 ; cmap ];  % Add black as the first color
```

The disadvantage is that if you use this colormap to display data with no `nan` values, the smallest value will also appear in black/white.

b) Use [sc](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16233) from the File Exchange, which renders an `imagesc` plot to an RGB image instead.  This is more flexible, because once you have the RGB image you can manipulate it however you wish, including changing all the `nan` values.  e.g.:

```
im = sc(myData);
im(repmat(isnan(myData), [ 1 1 3 ]) ) = 0;  % Set all the nan values in all three 
                                            % color channels to zero (i.e. black)
```

Comment: The first solution is no good since we are back to square one: nan and minimum values are the same color.
The second solution changes the image and when adding a data cursor the data shown is the RGB value instead of the actual value.